# how can i insert the values of my checkboxes into my database?

Tags: php, mysqli

i have here my codes regarding my checkboxes, but i got some errors when i click my submit button. though it prints all the values i selected on the checkbox but ive got an error on my sql script saying "Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\candidate\president2.php on line 21". i just want to save the values i selected on my database. pls help..

```
         <?php session_start(); ?>
         <?php
         //server info
          $server = 'localhost';
         $user = 'root';
         $pass = 'root';
        $db = 'user';

            // connect to the database
          $mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

          // show errors (remove this line if on a live site)
               mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);
           ?>
           <?php

           if ($_POST['representatives']){

         $check = $_POST['representatives'];
         foreach ($check as $ch){
           //this is my line 21 error. what i want here is to save the selected checkbox into my database but i got some error and i couldnt save it to my database
         mysqli_query("INSERT INTO sample (name) VALUES ('". $ch ."') ");
            echo  $ch. "<br>";
            }
            }
           ?>
     <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <html>
     <head>  
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
    function get_representatives_value()
     {
      for (var i=0; i < document.list.representatives.length; i++)

      {
     if (document.list.representatives[i].value = true)
    {
    return document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =document.list.representatives[i].value

    }
     }
     }

   //-->
    </script>
  title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <link href="candidate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   </head>
   <body> <p id="txt"></p>
   <form name="list" action="president2.php" method="post" onSubmit="return get_representatives_value()">
<div id="form"> 
     <?php
    // get the records from the database
     if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM candidate_info WHERE position= 'representatives' AND department ='CCEITE' ORDER BY cand_id"))
        {
      // display records if there are records to display
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
          {
           // display records in a table
        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";

         // set table headers
         echo "<tr><th>Student ID</th><th>Candidate ID</td><th>Course</th><th colspan = '3'>Name</th></tr>";

        while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
                  {
         // set up a row for each record
        echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row->cand_studid . "</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row->cand_id."</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row->course . "</td>";
     echo "<td coslpan ='5'>" . $row->fname . " ". $row->mname ." ". $row->lname ." </td>";
  echo "<td><input type ='checkbox' name='representatives[]' id='". $row->studid ."' value='" . $row->fname . " ". $row->mname ." ". $row->lname .  "'onchange='get_representatives_value()' /></td>";
 echo "</tr>";
                                    }
echo "</table>";
                            }
         // if there are no records in the database, display an alert message
                            else
                            {
          echo "No results to display!";
                            }
                    }
           // show an error if there is an issue with the database query
            else
                    {
                 echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
                    }

           // close database connection
           $mysqli->close();

    echo "<input type='submit' name='representatives  value='Submit' />";

       ?> 
   </div>
 </form>
    </body>
   </html>
```

heres the preview of my output, first pic is i selected 2 candidate and the other is one.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're mixing OOP and procedural `mysqli` functions.

Comment: the first arg of mysqli_query should be link or use $link-> see this doc http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: @ njk & farmer1992.. thank u for your advice, now i got what i need... thaks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

The mysqli_query function requires the $mysqli link to be the first parameter. There are two ways you can fix your error. Below is the **ERROR**

```
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO sample (name) VALUES ('". $ch ."') ");
```

To fix this simply change it to one of the two below > (Id use the first option because you already use it in your code somewhere.)

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO sample (name) VALUES ('". $ch ."') ");
```

OR

```
 mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO sample (name) VALUES ('". $ch ."') ");
```

Answer (score 0):

As it says, the function `mysqli_query()` expects at least two parameters. According to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), the first parameter should be:

> A link identifier returned by `mysqli_connect()` or `mysqli_init()`

Followed by the query as the second parameter. You don't appear to be using either of those functions in your code. Seeing that you declared a mysqli object, you probably meant to use `$mysqli->query()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Just take a look at my example and i'm hoping that it would helps you..:-

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['team']))
{
foreach($_POST['team'] as $value){
$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO team('team') VALUES ('$value')");
}
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="lol.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="team[]" value="IN"> India<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="team[]" value="DK"> Dark <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="team[]" value="LA"> lolax <br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem was with mysqli. While this does explain how to use the deprecated mysql_ functions, it does not address the problem here.

Comment: @TJohnW. 
 now my problem anymore is the counting of those candidate which are selected. it would be my pleasure if you would suggest me how to do it sir... but thanks again for your help...